# Jenkins Git Gradle S3 add middle step

Tags: git, jenkins, gradle, amazon-s3

i work on a java/gradle project that is currently built and deployed by a bash script. i need to convert to (first step) building with jenkins.

the current script checks out the develop branch, copies a properties file with passwords from our s3 bucket into the src/main/resources dir then does a gradle build.

my questions...

1. to copy the application properties file into the build area i was
   going to use a gradle task, is that the best way?
2. how do i set up gradle permissions to access s3 to work under jenkins, is there a good link for that?
3. i noticed examples of getting an artifact via gradle from s3 but how would i get a properties file from s3 and copy to a specific directory using
   gradle?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish the application properties file as a JAR to S3, and make the other project depend on it. All the operations can be done by the built-in plugins.

For your questions:

1. I do not know what the best way is. You could even use a `aws s3 cp` command copying the properties file into `src/main/resources` before build. For me, it is more important to make sure the IAM roles/users are set properly.
2. I'm not familiar with Jenkins, but it must have some way to store secrets and be able to export them via environment variables.
3. Take a look at the following example.

This example are run in Java 11 and Gradle 7:

#### Project `example-props`

```
./example-props
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── resources
            └── com/example/application.yml
```

```gradle
// example-props/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "maven-publish"
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1"

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "s3://YOUR-S3-BUCKET/YOUR-S3-PREFIX"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID") ?: ""
                secretKey System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY") ?: ""
                sessionToken System.getenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN") ?: null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Project `example-app`

```
./example-app
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── com/example/app/App.java
```

```gradle
// example-app/build.gradle
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "application"
}

application {
    mainClass = "com.example.app.App"
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url "s3://YOUR-S3-BUCKET/YOUR-S3-PREFIX"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID") ?: ""
            secretKey System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY") ?: ""
            sessionToken System.getenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN") ?: null
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "com.example:props:0.0.1"
}
```

```java
// example-app/src/main/java/com/example/app/App.java
package com.example.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class App {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream inputStream = Objects.requireNonNull(
        App.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/example/props/application.yml"));
    String content = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream)).lines()
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

    System.out.println("Yeah! " + content);
  }
}
```

#### Steps

```
$ cd ./example-props
$ ./gradlew publish

$ cd ../example-app
$ ./gradlew run

> Task :run
Yeah! spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://example.com:5432/postgres"
    username: postgres
    password: postgres-password

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

#### References

- Minimal example: https://github.com/chehsunliu/stackoverflow/tree/main/a.2021-08-06.gradle.67274035
- Maven Publish Plugin: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html
- Declaring repositories: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:supported_transport_protocols